# Looping backwards in python and getting the index

Tags: python

There are multiple ways to loop back in python
For example we have

```
arr=[5,6,8]
for i in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
  print(i," ",arr[i])
```

which gives

```
2   8
1   6
0   5
```

I can solve what I need with that, but I am curious. There is another way to loop back which is

```
for im in arr[::-1]:
  print(im)
```

Looks nice, right?
This gives

```
8
6
5
```

My question is, using this second method is there a way to get not only the element but also the index? (the 2,1,0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: Think about `enumerate` to get (index and num) as a tuple pair

Comment: If you need _only_ the index, analogous to `range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1)`, you can also use `reversed(range(len(arr)))`, which might be more intuitive and readable.

Answer (score 3):

use the builtin method reversed

```
arr = [5, 6, 8]
for i in reversed(range(0,len(arr))):
    print(i,arr[i])
```

Comment: While it's not very pythonic to use list indices in Python, this question might be a case of "keep it simple, s". I like this solution for its simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

There's a builtin for that: `reversed`. This might be more readable and intuitive than using a `range` or `slice` with negative step.

For just the index, you can pass the `range` to `reversed` directly:

```
arr = list("ABC")

for i in reversed(range(len(arr))):
    print(i, arr[i])                   
# 2 C
# 1 B
# 0 A
```

For index and element, you have to collect the `enumerate` iterator into a `list` before reversing:

```
for i, x in reversed(list(enumerate(arr))):
    print(i, x)                
# 2 C
# 1 B
# 0 A
```

Comment: wait, I don't get why the need of list, if the first code worked

Comment: @KansaiRobot `enumerate` returns a generic iterator/generator that can not be reversed directly. `range` is a special range-iterator that can be reversed directly because it's length is known a priori. In the case of `enumerate(arr)` you in fact also know the length, but you could also create an `enumerate` from e.g. a `zip`, `filter`, or any other kind of generator/iterator, and then it would not be possible, so `enumerate` in general can not be reversed, either, since you do not know the length or, in fact, the last element, before generating all the others..

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `reversed()` and `zip()` that should be memory efficient:

```py
arr = [5, 6, 8]

for idx, elem in zip(reversed(range(len(arr))),
                     reversed(arr)
                     ):
    print(idx, elem)
```

Output:

```
2 8
1 6
0 5
```

Comment: Neat, but should only be relevant if `arr` takes up ~half of your free RAM.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for idx, elem in list(enumerate(arr))[::-1]:
    print(idx, elem)
```

This uses enumerate to keep elements with their specific index. Then we convert it to list and reverse (enumerate result is not reversible without converting). No need to keep track of any order (like subtracting) manually

You can also just reverse the forward range:

```
for idx in range(len(arr))[::-1]:
   print(idx, arr[idx])
```

Python actually reverses range in a smart way, without converting it to a list, so it works even for big stuff:

```
>>> range(10)[::-1]
range(9, -1, -1)
```

This means that `range(len(arr))[::-1]` will work in exactly the same way, with exactly the same speed, as your `range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1)` while looking nice!

Comment: This forces however to consume the generator

Comment: @mozway its impossible to reverse-enumerate a sequence without knowing its length beforehand.

Comment: @mozway Ye, you cannot reverse a generator in any other way - but it's still less error-prone than manually counting indexes and works well for smaller stuff. In the meantime, I added another solution that's basically the same what OP posted originally with range but looks nicer.

Comment: @h4z3 this is a nicer approach ;)

Comment: Creating an entirely new list in memory just to iterate over is awful.

Comment: @salt-die For 10 minutes before you posted your comment, there's been a completely generator approach added to my answer which I openly say works the same as OP's original approach while looking nicer.

Comment: There's literally another user that posted exactly the same two approaches as me, later than me, just in different order than me. Still before your comment. But it's me who gets shitted on in comments and gets a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```py
i = len(arr) - 1
for im in arr[::-1]:
    print(i, " ", im)
    i -= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `enumerate` and subtract from the initial length:

```
arr=[5,6,8]
for i,im in enumerate(arr[::-1]):
    print(len(arr)-i-1, im)
```

output:

```
2 8
1 6
0 5
```

Comment: Perhaps because manually subtracting the indexes is unnecessarily complicated and error-prone.

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to iterate with an index is with `enumerate`. One can use this to index the other way by subtracting the index from the length of the sequence:

```py
In [51]: arr = [5, 6, 8]
    ...: for i, n in enumerate(arr):
    ...:     print(i, n)
    ...: 
0 5
1 6
2 8

In [52]: for i, n in enumerate(reversed(arr)):
    ...:     print(len(arr) - i - 1, n)
    ...: 
2 8
1 6
0 5
```

Note that `reversed` doesn't create a new list in memory and is preferable to `[::-1]` if just iterating.

Comment: interesting. `[::-1]` creates another list?

Comment: Yes, it creates an entirely new list.